Capturing stdout from InteractiveConsole.compile
I have the following code:
from code import InteractiveConsole
from io import StringIO
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

cons = InteractiveConsole()
code = cons.compile("2")
f = StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f):
    exec(code)
s = f.getvalue()
print("-" * 20)
print(s)

For some reason exec output is not captured by redirect_stdout. How can I capture output of exec?
This code is run in Jupyter notebook.

That's strange, when I execute your code, I get 2 as output. Where are you executing it?

You get 2 as the output on stdout probably, I want it captured as s. Oh wait, I'm running it as Jupyter notebok, I think that's the case.

I'm not really sure that I understand. Output is in variable s and it contains string 2, right?

Surprisingly, this code has different behaviour in Jupyter notebook and Python script.

If you try to compile print('2') it will return 2 to you even though you are in notebook since print is sending it's argument to stdout. When your code doesn't send anything to stdout as it is the case with only 2, I guess that's why notebook is not puting it in variable.

I think you are not completely understand the functionalities of the InteractiveConsole, the redirect_stdout should not be needed at all

@MilosStojanovic it's expected console behaviour to print 2 if you just put 2 in the code and it actually prints 2 when you put my code in Python script.

@cards If you have some better idea on how to capture output of this example command 2, then I'm happy to hear it. I don't think overriding InteractiveConsole.write works.

@MilosStojanovic I think that pointing out that I get my desired behaviour when working in Python script as opposed to Jupyter notebook solves my case. I guess running in Jupyter notebook messes up stdout somehow.

look at the source code of the command  line interface of sqlite3, it is newly introduced in Python 3.12. It is a good starting point:)

@cards I actually need exactly emulating Python console -  specifically Python console. This code shows how to implement your own console.

...look at the source code (copy-past it in your editor), change the line(s) where sql-code is execute with python-code (for ex eval) and voilà!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
